# Is it possible to get a router's public IP address from wireless access points without knowing the keys?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, router

I tried using `netsh` to view any connections while I have the "Enter security key" prompt up, but didn't get anything worth noting.

I know MAC addresses can be found. Is it possible to find IP addresses?

Comment: Do you not know your router's password?  It should be on it somewhere.  When you get access to your router you can google "what is my IP" and it will give it to you.  If you need your local IP info in windows you can type "ipconfig" in command prompt.  Here's a link about default router IP addresses http://www.techspot.com/guides/287-default-router-ip-addresses/.

Comment: What "Enter Passphrase" prompt are you talking about? The WEP passphrase? What keys are you talking about? Passwords? Or encryption keys?

Comment: A router does not have a public IP... It has another private network with (probably) your modem. The modem then has possibly a public IP, although some ISPs issue an additional private IP to your modem as well...

Comment: @AthomSfere, not entirely correct, modems can be bridged so they simply translate the layer 2 protocol to Ethernet and have nothing to do with the IP layer, which would allow the router to have a public IP.

Comment: @MaQleod yes, but that is such a niche concept (especially at the consumer level) that I am not sure it is relevant to the conversation. A fair point to my absolutism none-the-less.

Comment: @AthomSfere, the modem I use right now is bridged - most of the modems I have ever used across 3 different states and 8 ISPs, both cable and DSL, were also bridged - it isn't niche, it is a standard practice for many ISPs. The ISP I used to work for used bridged modems for all consumer line products. The business line products (SDSL,IDSL,T1) had routers. Even the EoC bundled service had a bridged connection.

Answer (score 0):

The AP acts only as an end point for the network it's attached to. The network itself has an external IP which can be discovered by visiting icanhazip.com, or doing a 'curl icanhazip.com' from the command prompt. If you mean to identify the external IP for a wireless network without joining it, that's an entirely different thing, and shouldn't be attempted on a network you don't have permissions to. I hope this answers your question.